# LXD containers: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: linux, access-control-list, containers

I'm running several LXD containers on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS host. All of the machines are ruinning 64bit Linux.

```
Linux <hostname> 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using ACLs (getfalc/setfacl) to configure the permissions of host mounted folders shared across different containers. While this works fine in general, for some folders I get the error message:

```
getfacl: <folder name>: Value too large for defined data type
```

I have several folders where this problem occurs in **all** containers, while it works fine on the host.

So far I could not figure out what makes these folders special.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem while looking for differences between the folders:

On the host some folders had ACLs with non-existing user accounts (1007 and 1009). I was reusing a data partition from an older installation, where these users existed.

After removing the ACL entries for these non-existint users on the host, the problem disappeared in the containers:

```
sudo setfacl -R -x u:1007 <path>
```